# Send object using json

Tags: php, json

Is there a recommended way of sending an object using json between a server and a client ?
Should I use only lower case for properties, should I use an object or an array ?

Update: this question came to me because by default php is encoding an associative array as an object ( after you decode it)

Comment: json is there so whats wrong in sending that

Comment: What “object” do you want to send and how would you want to use it on the client side?

Comment: `$data= json_decode($json, TRUE)` makes it into an array.

Answer (score 5):

You should make an array, then use PHP's [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) method.  It doesn't matter if the values are uppercase or lower case.

```
$a = array(
  'Test' => 42,
  'example' => 'Testing'
);

echo json_encode($a); // {"Test":42,"example":"Testing"}
```

When decoding in PHP, pass `true` as the 2nd parameter to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to convert objects to arrays.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? He's already aware of sending json between the client and server; he's just asking for best practice recommendations on the format of the data he sends.

Comment: @Spudley: I was suggesting he use an array for his data, and I edited the answer to show that the case doesn't matter.  Also, the question wasn't 100% clear either.

Comment: okay, I read the question as asking about what type of JSON syntax to use (ie `{}` or `[]`), but I can see how you could read it as asking about PHP usage too.

Comment: @Spudley: The question was tagged PHP, so I thought he asked how to use `json_encode`.  Also, `json_encode` will take care of `{}` and `[]` for you.

Comment: as you say, the question wasn't 100% clear one way or the other.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both these things are entirely up to you.

The casing of your property names is a coding style matter. It really doesn't matter as long as you are consistent -- your project should have fixed standards on this type of thing. If you haven't picked your standards yet, my advice is to go for readability, which usually means lower case or camel-case. I'd avoid upper case, and I'd also avoid using hyphens or underscores, but it is entirely up to you.

As for the choice between objects or arrays, that comes down to what is best suited to the data in question. If it needs named keys, then use an JSON object (ie with curly braces and key:value pairs `{'key':'value','key2':'value2'}`); if it doesn't, then use an JSON array (ie with square brackets and just values `['value1','value2']`). The choice is entirely down to how the data needs to be structured: both are perfectly valid in JSON and neither is better than the other; just used for different purposes.

(PHP, of course, doesn't differentiate -- both keyed and indexed data are stored in PHP arrays, so from the PHP side it makes absolutely no difference).

Answer (score 0):

Naming conventions aren't standardized, you can use whatever you like. It is a good idea to use names that are also valid javascript identifiers and won't clash with javascript keywords. Object vs. array is not a matter of convention, but rather one of meaning. A JSON object is a key-value collection, while an array is a flat list. Those are different things, and even though the syntax for both is somewhat interchangeable in javascript, and PHP can implement both using the same data type, you should make a clear distinction in your design. If it's a flat list, use `[]`. If it's a key-value thing, use `{}`. On the PHP side, simply use arrays for both: numerically-indexed arrays for `[]`, associative arrays for `{}`.